# SiriKit payment confirmation currency is always US$

Tags: ios, ios10, sirikit, intents-extension

I build Intents Extension and I'm handling INSendMoneyIntent and I'm saying:

> Send 25€ to John Smith

response after app confrimation

> Here's your <Your_App> payment for US$25.00. Do you want to send it?

Intent contains proper currency iso 3 code - EUR, so why siri displays wrong currency in payment confirmation?

returning intent

```
INSendPaymentIntentResponse *reponse = [[INSendPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendPaymentIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:userActivity];
completion(reponse);
```

Comment: plz, show some code?

Comment: addded, but seriously, there is no way that this is code fault, it's rather configuration problem?

Comment: With iOS 10 still in beta, you're probably better off [reporting this as a bug to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/) directly. And maybe posting in their beta forum.

Comment: Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow. (May I suggest setting a real username? Other users might be more inclined to answer. It's a small thing, but makes a huge difference.)

Comment: Did you solve the issue? @user3292998

Comment: yes, my app is in AppStore now ;) you can try to send money with Azimo ;D

Comment: @user3292998 could you please show how you fixed it? The accepted answer says you need to add paymentRecord, I do add a record but the confirmation is still always in US$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a paymentRecord to your response in

(void)confirmSendPayment:(INSendPaymentIntent *)intent

like so:

```
INSendPaymentIntentResponse *response = [[INSendPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendPaymentIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:userActivity];
response.paymentRecord = [[INPaymentRecord alloc] initWithPayee:intent.payee payer:nil currencyAmount:intent.currencyAmount paymentMethod:nil note:intent.note status:INPaymentStatusPending];
completion(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Julius' answer but it doesn't show where to set the currency. You can create a method

```
- (INPaymentRecord *) getPaymentRecord:(INSendPaymentIntent *)intent
{
    INCurrencyAmount *currAmount = [[INCurrencyAmount alloc] initWithAmount: intent.currencyAmount currencyCode:@"ZAR"];
    INPaymentMethod *paymentMethod = [[INPaymentMethod alloc] initWithType:INPaymentMethodTypeCredit name:@"" identificationHint:@"" icon:nil];
    INPaymentRecord *paymentRecord = [[INPaymentRecord alloc] initWithPayee:nil payer:nil currencyAmount: intent.currencyAmount paymentMethod:paymentMethod note:nil status:INPaymentStatusCompleted ];
return paymentRecord;
```

}

And then from the delegate method you just slot the paymentrecord assignment between your above two statements:

```
    INSendPaymentIntentResponse *response = [[INSendPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendPaymentIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil];

    **response.paymentRecord = [self getPaymentRecord:intent];**

    completion(response);
```

Comment: probably you are wrong, instance of intent is passed from `confirmSendPayment`, so basically all you need to do is set currency in `confirmSendPayment`